# Is it possible to get a delivery receipt for a remote Push Notification at the time of delivery?

Tags: ios

If a phone has turned off receipt of remote push notifications, or a push notification fails to be delivered, can the originator of the push get informed that it failed to be delivered?

I know there is the feedback service available to query for failed delivery attempts, but that sounds like its a pull type feedback rather than something like a receipt sent for every push notification.

So suppose we sent push notifications to 100,000 devices, could we then connect to the feedback service and see which ones failed? How accurate is this, is there a time delay before feedback info is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell if a push has been delivered.

The feedback service is designed to inform you of devices which have failed to deliver pushes for some time. You should act on the data in there and stop sending pushes to that device. It could take time to get into the feedback service though because it's only really meant to go in there when Apple have deemed that the device has uninstalled your app, or the device is no longer used, or a similar event rather than just the device is out of range at the moment and has no connection to APNS.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what Matt said, APNS provides a second, more immediate mechanism for becoming aware of ***some*** types of errors:  the error-response packets.  These packets are returned immediately while pushing notifications, providing you with live feedback when a supported error occurs and giving you the opportunity to take immediate action.  If a notification is accepted by APNS and no error-response packet is returned however, then the Feedback Service becomes the only way to know later if the notification reached the device or not (and even then, the conditions for becoming listed by the FeedbackService are not that simple).

The Feedback Service and the Error-Response Packets report different kinds of errors, so you cannot rely on any of them alone: you must deal with errors reported by both mechanisms.

Some libraries like [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/) deal with error-response packets automatically.

Comment: What sort of information is contained within the live feedback packets? What type of errors are listed in it?

Comment: This is fully documented in Apple's official APNS documentation.  See Table 5-1 for a list of error codes returned by APNS:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html