# Is it possible to determine if an app has been uninstalled on the device via the APN feedback system?

Tags: ios

If an app was installed on a device and then uninstalled, is there a way of determining this using the APN feedback service?

The feedback service is documented as saying its possible to know devices which aren't responding to notifications, but is additional information included, such why its not responding and when it first started non responding etc.?

Is there any way of determining if an app has been uninstalled? Or of knowing if an app is present of absent from a device?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no there isn't a way to determine if an app has been uninstalled.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747089/1068248) which might help:

> The feedback service is designed to inform you of devices which have
>   failed to deliver pushes for some time. You should act on the data in
>   there and stop sending pushes to that device. It could take time to
>   get into the feedback service though because it's only really meant to
>   go in there when Apple have deemed that the device has uninstalled
>   your app, or the device is no longer used, or a similar event rather
>   than just the device is out of range at the moment and has no
>   connection to APNS.

Basically, yes you could use the feedback service of APNS but it wouldn't conclusively tell you if a device had been uninstalled. If you need to know this then you're unfortunately going to have to change the way you're going about things as it's impossible to know (at present).